# How to initialize MobX store with async data (AsyncStorage) in React Native

Tags: react-native, mobx

We created a simple MobX store to save an object. This MobX store also syncs with AsyncStorage every time fooObject is changed:

```
import { observable } from 'mobx';

class FooStore {
  @observable fooObject = {};

  setFooObject(newFooObject) {
    this.fooObject = newFooObject;
    this.syncWithAsyncStorage();
  }

  syncWithAsyncStorage() {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('fooObject', JSON.stringify(this.fooObject));
  }
```

This mobx store is then consumed by various screens in the app.

As you can see, we use RN `AsyncStorage`, which is kind of a LocalStorage but for native apps, to always store the current state of `fooObject`.

The question is: when the app is closed, we loose FooStore state, so we want to retrieve the last 'save' we did to AsyncStorage (which is persisted).

The problem is AsyncStorage is (as the name states) an ASYNC function, and we can't wait for a promise resolution in FooStore's constructor.

How one would accomplish this initial state initialization of this MobX store based on the resolved return value of AsyncStorage?

We thought about writing an initialization method (async method) in FooStore like this:

```
async initializeFromAsyncStorage() {
  this.fooObject = await JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('fooObject'));
}
```

And then call this method on app initialization in our root App.js.

But I'm not sure if this would present unintended side effects and if this is idiomatic mobx/react-native.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I would create an initialization method. If the instance is *not* dependent of the initial data, you could call it right after the instantiation:

```
const fooStore = new FooStore()
fooStore.initializeFromAsyncStorage()
export default fooStore
```

Thill will not guarantee that the initial data is loaded when the app is constructed, but since the data is an optional observable, your app will react to it if/when it’s available.

Remember that `AsyncStorage.getItem` will resolve `null` if it has not been set, so you might want to do:

```
async initializeFromAsyncStorage() {
  const result = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fooObject')
  if (result !== null) {
    this.fooObject = JSON.parse(result)
  }
}
```